# stop opendkim from signing emails if it already has signature

Tags: postfix, centos7, opendkim

I am signing all the emails for all domains that goes through my postfix MTA, but I need to custom sign some emails for some domain from my application, is it possible to stop opendkim from signing emails if it already has signature?

Comment: caz that emails wiil be signed the client's domain d tag will be client's domain, so currently their emails gets via mydomain.com in the head of the email!

Comment: I understand *which* emails you with to exclude from your own signing, but not *why*. Do you realize that multiple signatures, such as one from client and one from the service provider (you) are typically strictly value *added*?

Answer (score 2):

There might be a way with OpenDKIM but you can at least do it in postfix with `header_checks`.

Create `/etc/postfix/header_checks` with:

```
/^DKIM-Signature: / FILTER smtp:127.0.0.1:10025
```

Then in `/etc/postfix/master.cf` make two changes.  First duplicate the SMTP listener so that it also listens on port 10025 but exclude the OpenDKIM milter.  To the listen port, add the `-o header_checks=regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks` option, e.g.

```
10025      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
smtp       inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
        -o header_checks=regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
        -o smtpd_milters=inet:localhost:8891
```

Obviously change this to the submission port (587) and preserve any other flags, as appropriate to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

The way with OpenDKIM is using the parameter *PeerList*

From http://www.opendkim.org/opendkim.conf.5.html: Identifies a set of "peers" that identifies clients whose connections should be accepted **without** processing by this filter.

My */etc/opendkim.conf* contains

```
PeerList                refile:/etc/opendkim/trusted
ExternalIgnoreList      refile:/etc/opendkim/trusted
InternalHosts           refile:/etc/opendkim/trusted
```

And the file */etc/opendkim/trusted* contains:

```
127.0.0.1
::1
localhost
```

This way, locally delivered mails e.g. via fetchmail are not signed.